# Only Account Team members should be visible in user selection while creating Opportunity Team Member based on custom picklist field value on Account

Tags: opportunity, account, account-teams, opportunity-teams

If Picklist value of Field A on Account Object is "Secured"

Only ATMs should be visible in User lookup field (on OTM Object) while creating OTMs

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You should [edit] your question to include more details.

Comment: I am just looking for the workaround for this scenario.

Whether this can be achieved or not. If Yes, than what's the best possible way to achieve this.